# get object that is inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
{"joker":{"baseMapId":"1536abe5e5504e5db380ccfaa9b6fd8d","customBaseMap":"","zoomn":"5","orient":"0","centLon":"-93.69999999999843","centLat":"38.64999999999935","baseMapLabels":"true"}}
{"batman":{"baseMapId":"1536abe5e5504e5db380ccfaa9b6fd8d","customBaseMap":"","zoomn":"5","orient":"0","centLon":"-93.69999999999843","centLat":"38.64999999999935","baseMapLabels":"true"}}
{"merman":{"baseMapId":"1536abe5e5504e5db380ccfaa9b6fd8d","customBaseMap":"","zoomn":"5","orient":"0","centLon":"-93.69999999999843","centLat":"38.64999999999935","baseMapLabels":"true"}}
```

My data looks like the above; how could I loop through and get data for batman, for instance.

I have tried `data['batman']` and `data[0][batman]` - my desired result is to get the whole like, *i.e.* below:

```
{"batman":{"baseMapId":"1536abe5e5504e5db380ccfaa9b6fd8d","customBaseMap":"","zoomn":"5","orient":"0","centLon":"-93.69999999999843","centLat":"38.64999999999935","baseMapLabels":"true"}}
```

Comment: What are all these dictionaries inside of - A list?

Comment: `const batman = data.find(x => x.batman);` will return the first batman in data (there could be more than one)

Comment: What is `data[1]` returning?

Comment: @alfasin reporting 'find' is not a function

Comment: your structure is object only not an array

Comment: can you `console.log(data)` and paste the exact output?

Comment: if the wrapping object is not an array then what is it? the information you provided in the question is not clear...

Comment: @alfasin I am not sure, but that is exactly how the data is in my data.json file - anyway to consume by username, i.e batman? the below two answers I am getting arr undefined and find undefined so do not think I can use those.

Comment: @emilioestevez because this is not a valid JSON format...
In a valid json file the json objects should be separated by commas and inside an array, e.g. `[{...}, {...}, {...}]`

Comment: @alfasin OK now I have it in this json format, how could I retrieve my user i.e. batman the below options are still working for me

Comment: @emilioestevez it's great that you have it in json format now, please share with us the format you're getting it (update the question)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your shared structure is wrong. It's not an array instead there are 3 objects written one by one so you've to get them into a proper array structure.

```
let arr = [{
  "joker": {
    "baseMapId": "1536abe5e5504e5db380ccfaa9b6fd8d",
    "customBaseMap": "",
    "zoomn": "5",
    "orient": "0",
    "centLon": "-93.69999999999843",
    "centLat": "38.64999999999935",
    "baseMapLabels": "true"
  }
}, {
  "batman": {
    "baseMapId": "1536abe5e5504e5db380ccfaa9b6fd8d",
    "customBaseMap": "",
    "zoomn": "5",
    "orient": "0",
    "centLon": "-93.69999999999843",
    "centLat": "38.64999999999935",
    "baseMapLabels": "true"
  }
}, {
  "merman": {
    "baseMapId": "1536abe5e5504e5db380ccfaa9b6fd8d",
    "customBaseMap": "",
    "zoomn": "5",
    "orient": "0",
    "centLon": "-93.69999999999843",
    "centLat": "38.64999999999935",
    "baseMapLabels": "true"
  }
}]
```

A structure like this can be searched by `Array.find()` just as shown below.

```
arr.find(el => Object.keys(el)[0] === 'batman' )
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [{
  "joker": {
    "baseMapId": "1536abe5e5504e5db380ccfaa9b6fd8d",
    "customBaseMap": "",
    "zoomn": "5",
    "orient": "0",
    "centLon": "-93.69999999999843",
    "centLat": "38.64999999999935",
    "baseMapLabels": "true"
  }
}, {
  "batman": {
    "baseMapId": "1536abe5e5504e5db380ccfaa9b6fd8d",
    "customBaseMap": "",
    "zoomn": "5",
    "orient": "0",
    "centLon": "-93.69999999999843",
    "centLat": "38.64999999999935",
    "baseMapLabels": "true"
  }
}, {
  "merman": {
    "baseMapId": "1536abe5e5504e5db380ccfaa9b6fd8d",
    "customBaseMap": "",
    "zoomn": "5",
    "orient": "0",
    "centLon": "-93.69999999999843",
    "centLat": "38.64999999999935",
    "baseMapLabels": "true"
  }
}]

const result = arr.find(x => 'batman' in x);
console.log(result)
```